# scala project, it gives me red error lines under def

Tags: scala

scala project, it gives me red error lines under def.

package ass1

```
object Main extends App {

}


def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
  if (c == 0 || c == r) 1
  else pascal(c - 1, r - 1) + pascal(c, r - 1)
}
```

and error is `scala multiple markers at this line expected class or object definition`

I don't understand why. need help.
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `def` must be within an enclosing scope. For instance within your `Main` object.